# convert date to YYMM format in sql for given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can we convert date format to YYMM(ex:1208) for the given date 25/08/2012.

Answer (score 4):

Use [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with style 12 and pick the first four characters.

```
select convert(char(4), getdate(), 12)
```

Comment: If the input is a string though, you'll need to convert to datetime first, and you'll need to know the input format to use the right style first so that 25/08/2012 is interpreted as DMY not MDY.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I used `getdate()` in my answer for a reason. If nothing else it would inspire the OP to come back with a comment asking what that is all about and why it does not work for him.

Comment: Wasn't complaining about your answer, just ensuring it was clear to the reader that a string won't necessarily be interpreted as nicely.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes, if the input is a string the style parameter will be ignored and the answer is a complicated way of doing `left('25/08/2012', 4)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @date date='08/25/2012'
 select CONVERT(varchar(4),@date,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the datatype for the value `25/08/2012`.

```
declare @dt char(10)
set @dt = '25/08/2012'

select right(@dt, 2) + substring(@dt, 4, 2)
```

Comment: Uh, thi sdoesn't come close to answering the question since it is asking about dates and not character strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff they do not specify if the value is actually of the datatype date.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like remembering the string convert formulas, you can also use:

```
declare @date date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
select right(CAST(year(@date) as varchar(4)), 2) + RIGHT('0'+cast(month(@date) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

It is a bit more cumbersome, but saves a trip to the help pages.

Comment: This is great if you have US English as language / regional settings, and MDY as DATEFORMAT. Please try this with SET DATEFORMAT DMY or SET LANGUAGE FRENCH. If you know the input format, and it's a string, what do you gain by implicitly converting it to a date when you ask for MONTH() and YEAR()? If you want to convert it to a DATE, why not perform a much safer explicit convert with style 101?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I don't get your comment at all.  The original question seemed to be about a date converted to a string, not a string converted to a string.  Are you saying that MONTH() and YEAR() won't work, depending on the regional settings?  By the way, the problem with CONVERT, for me at least, is remembering dozens of formats.  Why can't Microsoft just use YYYYMMDD format strings like everyone else?

Comment: At best, the question was ambiguous. Do you think if `25/08/2012` was surrounded in quotes (`'25/08/2012'`) you might think differently?

Comment: Also, did you try your very first line, all by itself, with SET LANGUAGE FRENCH or SET DATEFORMAT DMY? Please try it before saying you don't get my comment. You can't perform MONTH() or YEAR() on a variable that kills the batch because of an error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I see, you are adderssing the fact that I changed the format of the date in my example.  I guess that's valid.  My point was doing the conversion without remembering the CONVERT format, not the specific format for the date.  I just figure whoever uses it would use to correct date for their system.  But, I'm going to edit the answer to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your comment "Why can't Microsoft just use YYYYMMDD format strings like everyone else?" is incredibly naive. Internationalisation is a massive deal. Different countries use different formats - there is a date datatype for a reason (rather than using strings) as it allows dates to be stored internally in a generic fashion, yet queried/exposed to a client in the format that the user expects

Comment: @phil ... The comment was not about storing dates, which is mote often dine as a numeric of some sort.  It wad about converting them to strings.  As for naive, that would be the plethora of software, database and otherwise, that support flexible conversions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The list of conversion style numbers is at your fingertips. Do a search for [cast and convert](https://www.google.com/search?q=cast+and+convert) and it will be the first result every time. At least, it is for me with personalized search results on.